# How do I get the current time zone where my app resides

Tags: node.js, api, express, heroku, sms

I've been having this issue for months and I've finally made some headway. I'm writing an app the sends me a message at specific times, 9 am and 9 pm eastern time. When I ran it locally it worked perfectly but when I deploy it, I get nothing. I was messing around and then I saw this  [Heroku Logs](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ak9Oiv4PZ8lLg2OwLuTMnvgBSbbj). My guess is that my app is located on a server that is in a different time zone and when this code below runs. The conditions are never met and nothing gets sent. My question now is, is there a way I can get the current time of and compare regardless of what time zone the server is located?

```
const sendMessage = require('./sms-api.js');

const send = () =>{

    setInterval(()=>{

        var x = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
        console.log(x);
    
       if(x === '11:00:10 AM')
       {
           console.log('match');
           return sendMessage('6178032176', 'Good Morning');
       }
       else if(x === '9:50:20 PM')
       {
           console.log('match');
           sendMessage('6178032176', 'Good Evening');
       }
    },1000)
}

send();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with different timezones, it is better to **work in UTC** and then offset it according to required timezone.

Get the time in UTC and then offset it according to required timezone.

You can also use dedicated libraries like `moment-timezone`.

 https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/

Answer (score 1):

Like Suyash said above, your best option is to work entirely in UTC, and only convert when displaying times to users. Rather than dealing with offsets, you can append your dates and times with a 'Z' to indicate they are universal.

The best way I've found to do that is with moment.js and moment-timezone.js. Here is an example of an implementation that will allow you to convert times and dates: https://github.com/aidanjrauscher/browser-timezone-conversions. These libraries also make it very convenient to convert any date or time related user input back from their local time zone to UTC.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your help. I ended up figuring it out. I used this instead  `const time = new Date().toLocaleTimeString('en-US', { timeZone: 'America/New_York' });`.